# File.ReadAllBytesAsync cannot be cancelled

Tags: c#, io, task-parallel-library

I find the behavior of `File.ReadAllBytesAsync` is strange. If I cancel the task returned by `File.ReadAllBytesAsync`, it will still continue to run until the whole file is read. Here is the demo code. I call the Test method and compare the SHA256 of these two files(`fileFrom` and `fileTo`), I find they are same. The file read is about 1 GB and on a HDD, I think it is not possible to read the file in 10 ms. It seems that the cancellation is not working.

```
public async void Test(string fileFrom, string fileTo)
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task<byte[]> task = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(fileFrom, source.Token);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    source.Cancel();
    byte[] bytes = await task;
    Debug.WriteLine(bytes.Length.ToString());
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileTo, bytes);
}
```

**Edit**

@Panagiotis Kanavos found several bugs in code above, so I modified it and tested again with a near 2GB file, but the result is same. Here is the new version demo code which print `Test: 16264 ms, 2146435071 Bytes.`:

```
public async Task Test(string fileFrom, string fileTo)
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(20);
    Task<byte[]> task = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(fileFrom, source.Token);
    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    byte[] bytes = await task;
    watch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Test: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms, {bytes.Length} Bytes.");
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileTo, bytes);
}
```

Comment: Version of .NET? OS?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama .NET6, Windows 10 20H2

Comment: On my computer (Windows 11) with .NET 6, there's a limit of 2GB when reading bytes from a file. For me, it read the whole file in 1.3 seconds. With `Thread.Sleep(50)` it wasn't cancelled quickly enough to affect reading the file. With `Thread.Sleep(10)` it cancelled reading my 2 GB file before it could fully be read.  The problem here might be partly related to context switching, and perhaps how `ReadAllBytes` works internally.

Comment: @AlpacaMan the code you posted is full of bugs that can result in the unexpected behavior you describe. `async void Test` can't be awaited - `async void` is meant only for event handlers for this very reason. The calling thread is put to sleep with tells the OS to schedule to another thread. Given the minimum time slice is 16ms, sleeping for 10ms means it will take way more than just 10ms for the thread to get rescheduled. If you really want to test cancellation use an `async Task` method, use a CTS with a timeout passed in the constructor itself, and `await File.ReadAllAsync`

Comment: @AlpacaMan besides, tasks aren't threads and can't be aborted. CancellationTokens are used for *cooperative* cancellation, ie the async operation checks that token and exists gracefully when it's signaled. I'd expect an Exception when that happens, not a partial or full buffer. Given that you *can't* await `Test`, how are you sure it completed at all?

Comment: You can check [the source code in Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/File.cs#L875). If the token is cancelled you should get an exception, not a buffer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There was a line `Debug.WriteLine(bytes.Length.ToString());` after `await` so when this number was print I could be sure that this task completed. But I removed it because I thought it might distract you. Now I recover it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also, I put a break point at last line of `Test` method, so I am sure the task completes when the break point hit.

Comment: OK,  I'll accept you suggestion, pass a timeout to the CTS constructor, test again and update the question.

Comment: As a side-note, instead of `Thread.Sleep(10); source.Cancel();` you could also do `source.CancelAfter(10);`.